# Requiring all parameters or return 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to require the user to input all parameters into the URL like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/movies/1?foo=a&bar=c
```

The browser displays;

```
1 a c
```

I would like to ensure that all parameters are included in the URL, and the other combinations of parameters would result in `404`. **How do I modify the code to do this?**

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionConstraints;
using MoviesAPI.Services;

namespace MoviesAPI.Controllers
{
     public interface IActionConstraint : IActionConstraintMetadata
     {
        /// <summary>
        /// The constraint order.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Constraints are grouped into stages by the value of <see cref="Order"/>. See remarks on
        /// <see cref="IActionConstraint"/>.
        /// </remarks>


        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether an action is a valid candidate for selection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context">The <see cref="ActionConstraintContext"/>.</param>
        /// <returns>True if the action is valid for selection, otherwise false.</returns>
        bool Accept(ActionConstraintContext context);
     }

     public class RequiredFromQueryActionConstraint : IActionConstraint
     {
          private readonly string _parameter;

          public RequiredFromQueryActionConstraint(string parameter)
          {
               _parameter = parameter;
          }

          public bool Accept(ActionConstraintContext context)
          {
               if (!context.RouteContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.ContainsKey(_parameter))
               {
                    return false;
               }

               return true;
          }
     }

     public class RequiredFromQueryAttribute : FromQueryAttribute, IParameterModelConvention
     {
          public void Apply(ParameterModel parameter)
          {
               if (parameter.Action.Selectors != null && parameter.Action.Selectors.Any())
               {
                    parameter.Action.Selectors.Last().ActionConstraints.Add(new RequiredFromQueryActionConstraint(parameter.BindingInfo?.BinderModelName ?? parameter.ParameterName));
               }
          }
     }      

     [Route("api/[controller]")]
     public class MoviesController : Controller
     {
          private MoviesDbContext _context;
          public MoviesController(MoviesDbContext context)
          {
               _context = context;
          }
          public IActionResult GetMovies()
          {
               return Ok(_context.Movies);
          }

          [HttpGet("{id}")]
          public string Get(int id, [RequiredFromQuery]string foo, [RequiredFromQuery]string bar)
          {
               return id + " " + foo + " " + bar;
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`IActionConstraint` Interface is included in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionConstraints`.
 Remove your interface code and add the `Order` property for the `RequiredFromQueryActionConstraint`

```
public class RequiredFromQueryActionConstraint : IActionConstraint
{
    private readonly string _parameter;

    public RequiredFromQueryActionConstraint(string parameter)
    {
        _parameter = parameter;
    }

    public int Order => 999;
    public bool Accept(ActionConstraintContext context)
    {
        if (!context.RouteContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.ContainsKey(_parameter))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}

public class RequiredFromQueryAttribute : FromQueryAttribute, IParameterModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ParameterModel parameter)
    {
        if (parameter.Action.Selectors != null && parameter.Action.Selectors.Any())
        {
            parameter.Action.Selectors.Last().ActionConstraints.Add(new RequiredFromQueryActionConstraint(parameter.BindingInfo?.BinderModelName ?? parameter.ParameterName));
        }
    }
}
```

Refer to https://www.strathweb.com/2016/09/required-query-string-parameters-in-asp-net-core-mvc/